# Text created by drawTextOnPath make in center

Tags: android, view, path, ondraw

I try make text in center. Text added dynamically.

```
public class GraphicsView extends View {
private static final String MY_TEXT = "ORANGE";
private Path mArc;

private Paint mPaintText;

public GraphicsView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mArc = new Path();
    RectF oval = new RectF(100,200,340,260);
    mArc.addArc(oval, 135, -100);
    mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaintText.setTextSize(35f);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(MY_TEXT, mArc, 0, 10, mPaintText);
    invalidate();
}
}
```

Everything is fine, but if I want show another word - it plased not in center.
[image]
[image]

May I know how calculate center and placed words in it? Is it possible make on different screen resolutions?

Comment: tried using Paint.Align ?

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/4693713